# optimisation of full outer join in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Need help, I have a problem and I can't find a good solution for optimise full outer join in BigQuery. I looked into this resources https://patents.google.com/patent/US5963933, https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/04/19/full-outer-joins/ . I tried rewrite using union all and it works very fast, but I found that number of return rows will be different. The 2 tables have the same fields. Table1 is about 105 GB and table2 is about 50 GB. I would be very grateful if someone would share their knowledge

Need optimize this:

```
SELECT 
  distinct
  COALESCE(table1.field1, table2.field1)
  COALESCE(table1.field2, table2.field2)
  COALESCE(table1.field3, table2.field3)
FROM `table1` t1 FULL OUTER JOIN `table2`  t2
ON (t1.field1=t2.field1)
```

My efforts:

1.

```
WITH
  q3 AS (
  SELECT
    q.field1,
    q.field2,
    q.field3,
    'c' AS tid
  FROM
    `table1` t1),
  q AS (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(table1.field1, table2.field1)
    COALESCE(table1.field2, table2.field2)
    COALESCE(table1.field3, table2.field3)
    q3.tid
  FROM
    q3
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     `table2`  t2 
  ON
    q3.CITI_MTCH_ID=q4.CITIMATCH_ID )
SELECT
  COALESCE(table1.field1, table2.field1)
  COALESCE(table1.field2, table2.field2)
  COALESCE(table1.field3, table2.field3)
FROM
  `table1` t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `table2`  t2
ON
  (t1.field1=t2.field1)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT
    q.field1,
    q.field2,
    q.field3
  FROM
    q
  WHERE
    q.tid IS NULL)
```

2. 

```
SELECT
  field1_id,
  field2,
  field3
FROM (
  SELECT
    field1_id,
    field2,
    field3
  FROM
    `table` 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    field1_id,
    field2,
    field3
  FROM
    `table2` t2
  WHERE
    field1_id NOT IN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT field1_id
    FROM
      `table` t ) ) X



Expected:

The  table1                                         The  table2
NAME        ID       YEAR               NAME         ID          YEAR 
=======   =====   ============          =====     ======       =====    
John          1         10             TOM           2         120  
TOM           2         120             ALEX          3          17
ALEX          3          17             Blade         4         10 
Blade         4          NULL       



Result table 
NAME        ID       YEAR                    
=======   =====   ============          
John           1        10               
TOM           2         120                 
ALEX          3         17               
Blade         4         10(ex: data from table2)
```

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, why do you need to "optimize" the query?  BigQuery scales quite well, so more background would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your answer, I added to the post what results I expect